# Get visitors by month with php / mysql

Tags: javascript, php, date, filter

I'm trying to count visitor dates to see how many visits there are per month & post the result into a jquery chart.

Ok so this code below "works", but it somehow counts everything * 2. If there is 1 visitor this month it will output 2, why is that?

I would also like to know how can I make this code smaller? $jan $feb etc. seems not the way this should be done, but I'm a beginner so I don't really know how this code can be made smaller & better. Can somebody help me with this?

Database:

```
date
2016-11-17 16:36:12
```

Php:

```
$jan = ''; $feb = ''; $maa = ''; $apr = ''; $mei = ''; $jun = ''; $jul = ''; $aug = ''; $sep = ''; $okt = ''; $nov = ''; $dec = '';

    foreach($dates as $date){                       
            $month = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date->date);
            if($month ["month"] == '01'){$jan .= $month ["month"];}
            if($month ["month"] == '02'){$feb .= $month ["month"];}
            if($month ["month"] == '03'){$maa .= $month ["month"];}
            if($month ["month"] == '04'){$apr .= $month ["month"];}
            if($maand["month"] == '05'){$mei .= $month ["month"];}
            if($maand["month"] == '06'){$jun .= $month ["month"];}
            if($maand["month"] == '07'){$jul .= $month ["month"];}
            if($maand["month"] == '08'){$aug .= $month ["month"];}
            if($maand["month"] == '08'){$sep .= $month ["month"];}
            if($maand["month "] == '10'){$okt .= $month ["month"];}
            if($maand["month "] == '11'){$nov .= $month ["month"];}
            if($maand["month "] == '12'){$dec .= $month ["month"];}
    }
```

Comment: are you getting this data from the database?

Comment: Yes, from mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$arr = array()
foreach($dates as $date){ 
   $month = date('m',strtotime($date->date));
   $arr[$month][] = $date;
}
```

Here this code creates an array an takes month as key and append data for that month as values.

Comment: Hello Parth, how do I echo this? I tried to echo $date but it gives me errors and maybe I shouldn't echo $date. Please help.

Comment: Try print_r($date), you cant echo array, either use var_dump() or print_r()

Answer (score 0):

```
$visitsPerMonth = [];
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $month = date('m', strtotime($date->date));
    $visitsPerMonth[$month]++;
}
```

If $dates is originating in a SQL database, instead use a GROUP BY query.

Use json_encode() on $visitsPerMonth if your jQuery chart expects JSON input.

Answer (score 0):

As per you requirements if you are storing visits data in database then you can get the count from database query as per month like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitors YEAR(visited_date) = '2016' GROUP BY MONTH(visited_date)
```

> If there is 1 visitor this month it will output 2, why is that?

This is because you are concatenating the string and counting the length of string. The month is of 2 characters so every time it iterates it concatenated 2 characters per iteration. See the example bellow

**Case 1: $data has 1 date 2016-11-17 16:36:12**

```
$nov = ''; // at start
$nov .= $month ["month"]; //  date 2016-11-17 16:36:12
=> $nov .= '11'; //shorthand concatenation php
=> $nov = $nov . '11';
=> $nov = '' . '11';  // as $nov = '' at start

count($nov); // $nov have value '11' which has 2 character so output will be 2
```

**Case 2: $data has 2 dates 2016-11-17 16:36:12 2016-11-18 16:36:12**

```
$nov = ''; // at start
$nov .= $month ["month"]; //  date 2016-11-17 16:36:12
=> $nov .= '11'; //shorthand concatenation php
=> $nov = $nov . '11';
=> $nov = '' . '11';  // as $nov = '' at start
```

now $nov have value 11 in it.

```
$nov .= $month ["month"]; //  date 2016-11-18 16:36:12
=> $nov .= '11'; //shorthand concatenation php
=> $nov = $nov . '11';
=> $nov = '11' . '11';  // as $nov has vale 11 in it

count($nov); // $nov have value '1111' which has 4 character so output will be 4
```

If you want your code to work do like this

```
$jan = 0; $feb = 0; $maa = 0; $apr = 0; $mei = 0; $jun = 0; $jul = 0; $aug = 0; $sep = 0; $okt = 0; $nov = 0; $dec = 0;

    foreach($dates as $date){                       
            $month = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date->date);
            if($month ["month"] == '01'){$jan++}
            if($month ["month"] == '02'){$feb++;}
            if($month ["month"] == '03'){$maa++;}
            if($month ["month"] == '04'){$apr++;}
            if($maand["month"] == '05'){$mei++;}
            if($maand["month"] == '06'){$jun++;}
            if($maand["month"] == '07'){$jul++;}
            if($maand["month"] == '08'){$aug++;}
            if($maand["month"] == '08'){$sep++;}
            if($maand["month "] == '10'){$okt++;}
            if($maand["month "] == '11'){$nov++;}
            if($maand["month "] == '12'){$dec++;}
    }
```

But i will suggest you to do in array like this

```
$visitorData = ['01'=>0,'02'=>0,'03'=>0,'04'=>0,'05'=>0,'06'=>0'07'=>0,'08'=>0,'09'=>0,'10'=>0,'11'=>0,'12'=>0];
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $month = date('m', strtotime($date->date));
    $visitorData[$month]++;
}
```

Then JSON encode the array to feed it to the jquery

Hope this will help